# use both www and naked domain to point my heroku app

Tags: heroku, dns

I am having trouble to set both my www.domain.org and domain.org to point to Heroku rails app.

I did a CNAME from www to www.example.org.herokudns.com.
it works fine and my www.example.org point to my example.herokuapp.com

Concerning https://example.org

Should I do a 
CNAME from @ to example.herokudns.com ? 
ALIAS is only accepted for IPs with my domain provider..

I having trouble finding an answer in stackoverflow.

Should I use http://wwwizer.com/naked-domain-redirect ?
Do I have a solution without using a third party free service ?

Comment: Did you see [this](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/custom-domains#add-a-custom-root-domain)

Comment: IN A is only allowed for IPs with my domain provider, i tried with CNAME but it's not intended to work that way or am I wrong ? Should I change my domain provider ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    heroku domains:add example.com

    heroku domains:add www.example.com

    heroku domains:add *.example.com
```

This is to point your domain name from heroku side

Here is a youtube video to make it easier https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kKGSGT7mSnQ&t=29s

Please let me know if this does work

Comment: I tried and got further and green on Heroku side ! Thank to you both. On my domain provider side, I have no option for ALIAS so I tried CNAME, i will let you know in a couple of hours.

Comment: you never let him know

Answer (score 3):

For naked domain `example.com` you can use the forwarding functionality. If you have purchased domain from GoDaddy you can follow this:

Go to manage DNS and scroll down to forwarding section where you will see something like this:
[image]

You can choose `https` and forward to `www.example.com`. (You can also make your naked domain point to some other subdomain)