# Request from origin without www is redirected to SSL, but not if www is present

Tags: asp.net, ssl, heroku

a website I am hosting on Heroku with a domain and SSL I've bought at Namecheap is not correctly set up by me. Right now it looks like this:

request to: example.com redirects to https://www.example.com

request to: [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) does not redirect to SSL

request to: https://example.com causes time out.
Here's my redirect setup:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Since you have bought SSL from Namecheap, you can configure it using [Heroku SSL](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ssl) docs.

To redirect from `example.com` to `https://www.example.com` (You can use the forwarding functionality) Take a look at this answer: [use both www and naked domain to point my heroku app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52045188/use-both-www-and-naked-domain-to-point-my-heroku-app/62850655#62850655)

To redirect from `example.com` to https (SSL): you will have to create CNAME record as pointing to herokudns and not herokuapp

```
heroku domains
=== example Heroku Domain
example.herokuapp.com

=== example Custom Domains
Domain Name      DNS Target
---------------  --------------------------
example.com      <haiku>.herokudns.com
www.example.com  <haiku>.herokudns.com
```